# How to run Quantum ESPRESSO on Google Cloud Services or Amazon Web Services

Tags: quantum-espresso, high-performance-computing, quantum-dots, cloud-computing

As I am exploring material simulations one really hard truth that I have realized is that my gaming laptop is not at all going to cut it for my research work. Currently I am trying to find the absorption spectra of a quantum dot which has 45 atoms in total and I am using the PBE functional (so not that much accuracy). The geometrical optimization converged after 10-12 hours by running the executable for absorption spectra (`turbo_lanczos.x`) did not go that well. The computation ran for 23 hours after which my laptop gave out.

So I am looking for clusters which do not burn a big hole in my pocket. AWS and GCS came first to my mind. Although [I found a tutorial](http://star.mit.edu/hpc/documentation/ec2scripts/) for running on AWS **I am not sure how to know how many cores, nodes, RAM or instances I need**. I was also not able to find any such documentation for Google Cloud.

Could you guys help me with some guidance?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are some cloud services for computing?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/4635/what-are-some-cloud-services-for-computing)

Comment: Does this help you? https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1122/88

Comment: +1 but Is your question "how many cores/nodes, and how much RAM do I need?" or is it "is there a tutorial for using Google Cloud?"

Comment: If youre low on RAM and computational resources, I believe using linearly scaling codes like SIESTA would be a good alternative. Moreover since your working on a quantum dot have you tried codes utilizing a local basis like gaussian: https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_obtain_the_UV-VIS_Spectrum_using_Gaussian_09 or ORCA (its opensource)

Comment: @Thomas Thanks and that did help. So if I buy some space on Google collab I will be technically running everything on the google cloud right.

Comment: @NikeDattani I was actually looking for two things- 1. How many instances would I need on AWS EC2 for running calculations. 2. What is the general procedure for running a job on an HPC system

Comment: @AnoopANair do gaussian basis set DFT codes use lower computational power than plain waves one ??

Comment: @ParmeetSinghEP066 That depends on the elements your considering. It would be expensive if you're trying to simulate quantum dots of heavy elements. I'm not a fluent user of Gaussian so I'm not entirely sure! :)

Comment: Any update on your journey towards solving this problem @ParmeetSinghEP066? I also tried to ping you in a chat room recently.

Comment: Hi, sorry but I actually stopped using Quantum Espresso as I started working under a different professor and we are currently using Gaussian and I actually have access to an HPC..

Comment: I'll probably close the question than since its not necessarily of interest to you anymore and I think the more general question is addressed by some of the other posts mentioned in the comments. It can be reopened if someone wants to add an answer for this specific case.